# How to use multiple <router-outlet> with Angular

Tags: html, css, angular

I've used router outlets many times, but never thought of using many of them. I basically thought about this when I was trying to make a login page with a navigation bar in it, and then I though what if I made multiple navigation bars in one page.

I tried to search the angular documentation but I understood nothing, absolutely nothing. The last thoughts were come and ask my question here in stack overflow.

```html
<div class="row no-gutters">

  <div class="leftside">
    <img src="assets/truck.jpeg">
  </div>

  <div class="rightside">
    <h1 class="title">Route Optimization</h1>
    <br>
    <app-loginbar></app-loginbar>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>

</div>
```

[Login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bNkuY.png)
[Forgot Password](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q2u3l.png)

This is basically my login page / forgot password, as you can see I have a navigation bar and my router outler tag under it.

```html
<ul class="nav justify-content-center">
    <li class="nav-item">
        <button class="nav-button-left" (click)="changeSignIn()">
            <h3 class="navelement" id="signin" style="border-bottom: 2px solid gray;">Sign In</h3>
        </button>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <button class="nav-button-right" (click)="changeForgot()">
            <h3 class="navelement" id="forgot">Forgot Password</h3>
        </button>
    </li>
</ul>
```

My navigation bar is nothing but a list of two buttons:
- Both update the underline of the navigation bar and moves from a component to another using this function:

```js
this.router.navigateByUrl("...");
```

What I want is have a completely new page. I don't want the login / forgot password navigation bar to appear. And this is what I am facing:

[Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4wxUD.png)

As you can see, I have the navigation bar and "main works!" too, I only want a new total page with "main works!" to appear.

I'm not facing any error, I just don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for `named router outlets`. With this, one can have multiple `router-outlets` on a page where only one can be left unnamed. In your route configuration, you need to specify the `outlet` property in order to specify which component should load in which outlet

Documentation at: https://angular.io/guide/router#displaying-multiple-routes-in-named-outlets

Comment: Doesn't help me at all.

Answer (score 0):

First before you start think of your app structure how you want to setup everything. What i mean with that is to do a sketch of your pages, how you want to name them and so on... later on you can setup your routing.

For example this is a excerpt of one of my apps:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: MainComponent, children: [
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
    { path: 'blog', loadChildren: () => import('../modules/blog/blog.module').then(m => m.BlogModule)},
    { path: 'about', component: AboutComponent },
    { path: 'contact', component: ContactComponent },
    { path: 'legal', component: ImpressumComponent },
    { path: 'privacy', component: PrivacyComponent },
    { path: 'signin', component: SigninComponent },
    { path: 'signup', component: SignupComponent },
    { path: 'signout', component: SignoutComponent },
    { path: '**', component: NotFoundComponent }
  ]}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Here in this example the `MainComponent` has one `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` and the `blog` pages are loaded by lazy loading, that also means, that the `BlogModule` has it's own `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` and routing configuration. That will be imported there with `RouterModule.forChild(routes)`. For more information you have to dive deeper into the doc's and their example Heroes App.

Import that routing module into your main `AppModule`:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    AboutComponent,
    PrivacyComponent,
    ImpressumComponent,
    NotFoundComponent,
    ContactComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

For your navigation you can just simply setup your `routerLink` attributes:

```html
<mat-toolbar color="primary">
  <app-page-content>
    <a routerLink="/home" mat-button><i class="material-icons" style="margin-bottom: 3px">home</i> Home</a>
    <a routerLink="/blog" mat-button><i class="material-icons" style="margin-bottom: 3px">dashboard</i> Blog</a>
    <a routerLink="/about" mat-button><i class="material-icons" style="margin-bottom: 3px">person</i> About</a>
    <a routerLink="/contact" mat-button><i class="material-icons" style="margin-bottom: 3px">mail</i> Contact</a>
    <span class="flex-spacer"></span>
    <a routerLink="signin" mat-button><span class="mi mi-person"></span></a>
  </app-page-content>
</mat-toolbar>
```

If you don't understand all this things i recommend you heavily to watch a angular crash course. Just type in YouTube "Angular Crash Course 2019", there is a pretty good one!

Answer (score 0):

What you needed is two navigation bars, or call the navigation bars with different parameters to indicating what to show on the top, and put them **inside** `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`. Because what you want is showing different things (navigation links) on different pages.

Comment: Doesn't help me at all.